# Explore Charts to Pdf Using silverlight 4.0?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, infragistics

I am using Infragistics control to design a chart in Silverlight 4.0.
       I have created that one.
       Now I want to explore the data from that data chart to PDf.
       How can I do it? Could you please anyone provide me information regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIElements to Teleriks `RadRichTextBox` and then export the document to PDF. This also gives you the ability to add some additional styling (header, border, description etc) to the PDF document before saving.

[This should get you started](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/general-discussions/export-uielement-to-pdf-in-silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you render the XamDataChart to a bitmap, you can add that to a PDF using the [Infragistics Document Engine](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/waw-infragistics-document-engine).  There is a [WPF Data Chart to PDF](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/tom_puglisi/posts/wpf-data-chart-to-pdf) blog post that demonstrates this and has a sample.  Note that this is using WPF and you will likely need to use the WPF XamDataChart on your webserver to generate the chart and add it to the PDF document for the end user to download.